# Force network operator

Tags: mobile-network, network-signal, apn

I'm getting my phone service through a medium sized company in my country, which means they have their own LTE network (called ice+). With my current plan I have practically free use of this network, but in the cases I can't find that network, my phone will automatically connect to their backup one (called ice, which I believe they access through a cooperation with a larger company), of which I have a small limit on data usage. This has been working out great for the past half year, but recently my phone has started changing the network operator from ice+ to ice randomly, even though I know it has access to ice+ (it will change to and stay on ice when I'm at home, even though the phone has been lying in the same place the whole time). Even if I manually select ice+ (which takes a few minutes to find because of searching), the phone will automatically change back to ice without me touching it at all.

Because of this I need a way to lock my phone to ice+, so I won't have to deal with restricted access and high bills, which should be completely unnecessary. Does someone know how I could do that, if there's something I can change in the APN settings, or maybe some app I can download that will do it for me? Even something that will check the network and automatically change back to ice+ would be okay, if not as convenient.

For reference I use an LG G6.

Comment: Automatic network selection is by default a job of the SIM card if I remember correctly. Seems like your operator has updated the SIM card over the air. But in your case the network technology switch could ba an option if it allows to set the device to 4g only.

Comment: How would thay work though? ice is also a 4G network, so wouldn't it connect just the same?

Comment: Sorry then forget my idea. Your question seemed to indicate that only ice+ is a LTE network.